# python AttributeError: module 'scapy.layers.http' has no attribute 'HTTPREQUEST'

Tags: python, http, scapy

I am trying to run this code to sniff the network traffic and print out the "Host" portion of the request.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http

def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)

def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        url = packet[http.HTTPREQUEST].Host
    
sniff("eth0")
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sniffer_05.py", line 21, in <module>
    sniff("eth0")
  File "sniffer_05.py", line 6, in sniff
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 972, in sniff
    sniffer._run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 925, in _run
    session.on_packet_received(p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/sessions.py", line 47, in on_packet_received
    result = self.prn(pkt)
  File "sniffer_05.py", line 10, in process_sniffed_packet
    url = packet[http.HTTPREQUEST].Host
AttributeError: module 'scapy.layers.http' has no attribute 'HTTPREQUEST'
```

Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

the class is `http.HTTPRequest` and not `http.HTTPREQUEST`